# Google Oauth and API quotas consumption

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to understand the API consumption count for Google services & quotas limitations (and where it would be applied).

I am requesting user to synched their personnal Google account via my application using GoogleOAuth2.0 authentification.

When I am going to use their authentification to make requests in their behalf, is the API quotas will be reduced from their own accounts ? or from my global account where the OAuth2.0 is created ?

For example Google Analytics have limits of 50k/day requests is that limits applied to only One customer that synch and I am using his credit or the 50k/day is applied on my own application account ? (hence limiting my ability to manage multiple clients).

Thanks for the precision maybe it's better that the user create a serviceaccount and I connect with it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API consumption is charged against the quota of the project that contains the OAuth Client ID.

Some of a project's quotas are measured *per user* (for ex, *Queries per minute per user*). To protect against a situation where a single user (or a small number of users) consume too much of the overall quota, you can pass the [`userQuota` parameter](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage#limiting_requests_per_user) as a hint:

> Identifies the user that the per-user quota will be charged against. If not specified, the authenticated principal is used.

A client can also pass the extra parameter `$userProject` to (voluntarily) charge against a different project's quota. The caller must have `serviceusage.services.use` permission on the project for that to work.

Comment: I am still having trouble to understand. From this link it's saying that: Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, and user consent is not required. (In non-service-account scenarios, your application calls Google APIs on behalf of end-users, and user consent is sometimes required.). Since it's on the behalf is still on the application that the service is accounted or end user account? https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2?hl=en